# How to sequence lines in files if some lines are strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed, seq

I encountered a problem with bash, I started using it recently.
I realize that lot of magic stuff can be done with just one line, as my previous question was solved by it.
This time question is simple:

I have a file which has this format

```
2 2 10
custom
8 10
3 5 18
custom
1 5
```

some of the lines equal to string `custom` (it can be any line!) and other lines have 2 or 3 numbers in it.
I want a file which will sequence the line with numbers but keep the lines with custom (order also must be the same), so desired output is

```
2 4 6 8 10
custom
8 9 10
3 8 13 18
custom
1 2 3 4 5
```

I also wish to overwrite input file with this one.
I know that with seq I can do the sequencing, but I wish elegant way to do it on file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk '/^([[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]+){2,3}[[:blank:]]*$/ {
   j = (NF==3) ? $2 : 1
   s=""
   for(i=$1; i<=$NF; i+=j)
      s = sprintf("%s%s%s", s, (i==$1)?"":OFS, i)
   $0=s
} 1' file

2 4 6 8 10
custom
8 9 10
3 8 13 18
custom
1 2 3 4 5
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^([[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]+){2,3}[[:blank:]]*$/` - match only lines with 2 or 3 numbers.
- `j = (NF==3) ? $2 : 1` - set variable `j` to `$2` if there are 3 columns otherwise set `j` to `1`
- `for(i=$1; i<=$NF; i+=j)` run a loop from 1st col to last col, increment by `j`
- `sprintf` is used for formatting the generated sequence
- `1` is default awk action to print each line

Comment: custom can be any line, perhaps also `1 strange line`. Not clear from the question, upvote for straight forward solution.

Comment: It didn't work. Maybe I should've been clearer, any line can equal to custom and it will literally be the string "custom", other lines can have 2 or 3 numbers, and it can be any number in the line, I test this code for file which was 2 2 10; custom; 2 6 10; custom; 1 5 (; represent line), note that for 2 6 10 output should be 2 6 - I literally want to do seq command on any line that doesn't equal to custom

Comment: If it helps, file can have 1, 2 or 3 lines. I didn't mention that because I wanted more general solution. since max number of lines in file is 3 I can solve this problem manually by a lot if else statements which would handle all 8 cases, but I was hoping for more elegant solution.

Comment: Like seq does it, 2 3 4 5 6 (if step is unspecified it will equal to 1)

Comment: I apologize, it works now. But when I enter it as copy - paste code as above it just prints the content of file1, when I enter in in one line as in your demo it works perfectly. Do you have explanation for this? I am very new to bash.

Comment: I broke in multiple lines for readability purpose. Otherwise `awk '/^([[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]+){2,3}[[:blank:]]*$/{j = (NF==3) ? $2 : 1; s=""; for(i=$1; i<=$NF; i+=j) s = sprintf("%s%s%s", s, (i==$1)?"":OFS, i); $0=s} 1' file` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, seq and paste):

```
sed '/^[0-9]/s/.*/seq & | paste -sd\\  /e' file
```

If a line begins with a digit use the lines values as parameters for the seq command which is then piped to paste command. The RHS of the substitute command is evaluated using the `e` flag (GNU sed specific).